# Double filters showing on web view on Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm having a problem with my woocommerce theme, flatsome, but I think the problem is with the widget. The standard woocommerce product filter.

In the web view it shows normally, but on the mobile view the filter gets doubled;

a filter which gives you the standard mobile view-type of filter that pops on the side when clicked,

and another filter which gives an ugly dropdown.

This is the image on mobile view, the one on top has the right filter I want, the one under gives the ugly dropdown

[image]

Here's the code of the filter:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: WooCommerce Product Filter
Plugin URI: http://www.mihajlovicnenad.com/product-filter
Description: Advanced product filter for any Wordpress template! - mihajlovicnenad.com
Author: Mihajlovic Nenad
Version: 6.3.0
Author URI: https://www.mihajlovicnenad.com
Text Domain: prdctfltr
*/

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

if ( !class_exists( 'PrdctfltrInit' ) ) :

    final class PrdctfltrInit {

        public static $version = '6.3.0';

        protected static $_instance = null;

        public static function instance() {

            if ( is_null( self::$_instance ) ) {
                self::$_instance = new self();
            }
            return self::$_instance;
        }

        public function __construct() {
            do_action( 'prdctfltr_loading' );

            $this->includes();

            $this->init_hooks();

            do_action( 'prdctfltr_loaded' );
        }

        private function init_hooks() {
            register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( $this, 'activate' ) );
            add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'check_version' ), 10 );
            add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'init' ), 0 );
        }

        private function is_request( $type ) {
            switch ( $type ) {
                case 'admin' :
                    return is_admin();
                case 'ajax' :
                    return defined( 'DOING_AJAX' );
                case 'cron' :
                    return defined( 'DOING_CRON' );
                case 'frontend' :
                    return ( ! is_admin() || defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) && ! defined( 'DOING_CRON' );
            }
        }

        public function includes() {

            include_once( 'lib/pf-characteristics.php' );
            include_once( 'lib/pf-widget.php' );
            include_once( 'lib/pf-fixoptions.php' );

            if ( $this->is_request( 'admin' ) ) {

                add_action( 'vc_before_init', array( $this, 'composer' ) );
                include_once ( 'lib/pf-settings.php' );
                $purchase_code = get_option( 'wc_settings_prdctfltr_purchase_code', '' );

                if ( $purchase_code ) {
                    require 'lib/update/plugin-update-checker.php';
                    $pf_check = PucFactory::buildUpdateChecker(
                        'http://mihajlovicnenad.com/envato/verify_json.php?k=' . $purchase_code,
                        __FILE__
                    );
                }

            }

            if ( $this->is_request( 'frontend' ) ) {
                $this->frontend_includes();
            }
        }

        public function frontend_includes() {
            include_once( 'lib/pf-frontend.php' );
            include_once( 'lib/pf-shortcode.php' );
        }

        public function include_template_functions() {

        }

        public function init() {

            do_action( 'before_prdctfltr_init' );

            $this->load_plugin_textdomain();

            do_action( 'after_prdctfltr_init' );

        }

        public function load_plugin_textdomain() {

            $domain = 'prdctfltr';
            $dir = untrailingslashit( WP_LANG_DIR );
            $locale = apply_filters( 'plugin_locale', get_locale(), $domain );

            if ( $loaded = load_textdomain( $domain, $dir . '/plugins/' . $domain . '-' . $locale . '.mo' ) ) {
                return $loaded;
            }
            else {
                load_plugin_textdomain( $domain, FALSE, basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/lang/' );
            }

        }

        public function setup_environment() {

        }

        public function plugin_url() {
            return untrailingslashit( plugins_url( '/', __FILE__ ) );
        }

        public function template_path() {
            return apply_filters( 'prdctfltr_template_path', '/templates/' );
        }

        public function plugin_path() {
            return untrailingslashit( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );
        }

        public function plugin_basename() {
            return untrailingslashit( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) );
        }

        public function ajax_url() {
            return admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php', 'relative' );
        }

        public function version() {
            return self::$version;
        }

        public function composer() {
            require_once( 'lib/pf-composer.php' );
        }

        function check_version() {

            $version = get_option( 'wc_settings_prdctfltr_version', false );

            if ( $version === false ) {
                $check = get_option( 'wc_settings_prdctfltr_always_visible', false );
                if ( $check === false ) {
                    update_option( 'wc_settings_prdctfltr_version', self::$version, 'yes' );
                    return '';
                }
                else {
                    $version = get_option( 'wc_settings_prdctfltr_version', '5.8.1' );
                }
            }

            if ( version_compare( '5.8.2', $version, '>' ) ) {
                add_action( 'admin_init', array( &$this, 'fix_database_582' ), 100 );
            }

            if ( version_compare( '6.0.6', $version, '>' ) ) {
                add_action( 'init', array( &$this, 'fix_database_606' ), 100 );
            }

        }

        function fix_database_606() {
            global $wpdb;

            $default = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT `option_name`, `option_value` FROM `$wpdb->options` WHERE `option_name` LIKE CONVERT( _utf8 'wc_settings_prdctfltr_%'USING utf8mb4 ) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci LIMIT 99999" );

            if ( !empty( $default ) ) {
                $fix_default = array();
                include_once( 'lib/pf-options-autoload.php' );

                foreach( $default as $k => $v ) {
                    if ( in_array( $v->option_name, $forbidden_std ) ) {
                        $wpdb->query( "update $wpdb->options set autoload='yes' where option_name = '$v->option_name';" );
                    }
                    else if ( in_array( $v->option_name, $dont_autoload_std ) || substr( $v->option_name, 0, 41 ) == 'wc_settings_prdctfltr_term_customization_' || substr( $v->option_name, 0, 43 ) == 'wc_settings_prdctfltr_filter_customization_' ) {
                        $wpdb->query( "update $wpdb->options set autoload='no' where option_name = '$v->option_name';" );
                    }
                    else if ( in_array( $v->option_name, $autoload_std ) ) {
                        $wpdb->query( "update $wpdb->options set autoload='yes' where option_name = '$v->option_name';" );
                    }
                    else if ( strpos( $v->option_name, 'transient' ) ) {
                        delete_option( $v->option_name );
                    }
                    else {
                        $fix_default[$v->option_name] = get_option( $v->option_name );
                        $wpdb->query( "update $wpdb->options set autoload='no' where option_name = '$v->option_name';" );
                    }
                }

                if ( !empty( $fix_default ) ) {
                    $fix_default = json_encode( $fix_default );
                    update_option( 'prdctfltr_wc_default', $fix_default, 'no' );
                }

                $templates = get_option( 'prdctfltr_templates', array() );
                if ( !empty( $templates ) && is_array( $templates ) ) {
                    update_option( 'prdctfltr_backup_templates', $templates, 'no' );
                    foreach( $templates as $k1 => $v1 ) {
                        if ( !empty( $v1 ) && substr( $v1, 0, 1 ) == '{' ) {
                            update_option( 'prdctfltr_wc_template_' . sanitize_title( $k1 ), $v1, 'no' );
                            $templates[$k1] = array();
                        }
                    }
                }
                update_option( 'prdctfltr_templates', $templates, 'no' );
            }
            update_option( 'wc_settings_prdctfltr_version', self::$version, 'yes' );

        }

        function fix_database_582() {

            global $wpdb;

            $wpdb->query( "update $wpdb->options set autoload='yes' where option_name like '%prdctfltr%';" );
            $wpdb->query( "delete from $wpdb->options where option_name like '_transient_prdctfltr_%';" );
            $wpdb->query( "delete from $wpdb->options where option_name like '_transient_%_prdctfltr_%';" );
            $wpdb->query( "delete from $wpdb->options where option_name like 'wc_settings_prdctfltr_%_end';" );
            $wpdb->query( "delete from $wpdb->options where option_name like 'wc_settings_prdctfltr_%_title' and option_value = '' ;" );
            delete_option( 'wc_settings_prdctfltr_force_categories' );
            delete_option( 'wc_settings_prdctfltr_force_emptyshop' );
            delete_option( 'wc_settings_prdctfltr_force_search' );
            delete_option( 'wc_settings_prdctfltr_caching' );
            delete_option( 'wc_settings_prdctfltr_selected' );
            delete_option( 'wc_settings_prdctfltr_attributes' );
            update_option( 'wc_settings_prdctfltr_version', '6.0.5', 'yes' );

        }

        function activate() {

            if ( false !== get_transient( 'prdctfltr_default' ) ) {
                delete_transient( 'prdctfltr_default' );
            }

            $active_presets = get_option( 'prdctfltr_templates', array() );

            if ( !empty( $active_presets ) && is_array( $active_presets ) ) {
                foreach( $active_presets as $k => $v ) {
                    if ( false !== ( $transient = get_transient( 'prdctfltr_' . $k ) ) ) {
                        delete_transient( 'prdctfltr_' . $k );
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }

    function Prdctfltr() {
        return PrdctfltrInit::instance();
    }

    PrdctfltrInit::instance();

endif;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple CSS should be able to fix this. Use media queries to hide the filter with the ugly dropdown on small screens.

Something like:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .filter-dropdown{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Substitute `filter-dropdown` with the class name of that filter. Substitute 768px with whichever number of pixels is right for your situation.

Without you pasting code we can't be more specific than that.

Comment: Hello sir, I did what you suggested and came up wiith this:

`@media only screen and (max-width: 48em) {
/*************** ADD MOBILE ONLY CSS HERE  ***************/
.prdctfltr{
        display: none;
    }
}

}
`

but did not work, I have just pasted the code of the filter plugin I have.

Comment: @Jed Hart You need to add the code I've suggested to the CSS.